# Modsecurity rule for blocking a request when a parameter doesn't meet a regex

Tags: regex, rules, mod-security, mod-security2

I am trying to create modsecurity rule which needs to block a request when a parameter doesn't meet a certain regex.
Let's take an [email regex](http://emailregex.com/) as example: `(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)`

and for the parameter: email
location of the page (needs to be included in the rule): /signup.php

What I tried (but I assume is not correct at all):

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@contains signup.php" "id:1,t:none,block,chain"
SecRule ARGS:email "!@rx wtvr" "t:none"
```

So if someone posts a get request like: "/signup.php?email=alert..." it will be blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a possible solution:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@contains signup.php" "id:1,phase:2,log,deny,status:503,msg:'custom email hack detected',chain"
SecRule ARGS:email "!@rx (^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)" "t:none"
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Though I would say that specific checks like this probably belong in your app rather than a WAF if at all possible.